# JavaScript: onClick event works without firing

Tags: javascript, html

I'm modifying a template taken from somewhere on the internet. Here, pagination is done. The end page will have the form submission. I tried to modify it without affecting any of the CSS. So I didn't change the tag to button. I'm using anchor tag with an onClick event which will submit the form. But the onClick event works on page loading instead of onClicking.

```
function renderPagination(wizard, options, state) {
  if (options.enablePagination) {
    var pagination = "<{0} class=\"actions {1}\"><ul role=\"menu\" aria-label=\"{2}\">{3}</ul></{0}>",
      buttonTemplate = "<li><a href=\"#{0}\" role=\"menuitem\">{1}</a></li>",
      submitButtonTemplate = "<li><a href = \'#{0}\' onClick=" + document.getElementById('studentForm').submit() + " role=\"menuitem\">{1}</a></li>",
      buttons = "";

    if (!options.forceMoveForward) {
      buttons += buttonTemplate.format("previous", options.labels.previous);
    }

    buttons += buttonTemplate.format("next", options.labels.next);

    if (options.enableFinishButton) {
      buttons += buttonTemplate.format("finish", options.labels.finish);
    }

    if (options.enableCancelButton) {
      buttons += buttonTemplate.format("cancel", options.labels.cancel);
    }

    wizard.append(pagination.format(options.actionContainerTag, options.clearFixCssClass,
      options.labels.pagination, buttons));

    refreshPagination(wizard, options, state);
    loadAsyncContent(wizard, options, state);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually passing the JS to be executed into the string template, you're actually executing that JS and inserting the `toString` result of that execution into the template, your variable assignment should be:

```js
      submitButtonTemplate = "<li><a href = \'#{0}\' onClick=" + "\"document.getElementById('studentForm').submit()\"" + " role=\"menuitem\">{1}</a></li>",
```

Comment: Yeah. I tried this. But the onClick event doesn't work when fired

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to escape the quotations around the JavaScript. I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Works!! Awesome!